# Передача данных между контроллерами с сохранением

Tags: ios, ipad

Как сделать передачу данных между `ViewController`, т.е. из одного контроллера в другой?
Я хочу сделать на одном контроллере ввод данных (настройки), а на другом эти данные выводить.
Если можно, подскажите пример, пожалуйста!

```
ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *log;

- (IBAction)vper:(id)sender;

@end     

ViewController.m                                                                                                                   #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void) someButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    ViewController2 *classB = [[ViewController2 alloc] init]; //создаете экземпляр класса
    classB.textFieldValue = _log.text; // присваеваете значение переменной
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)vper:(id)sender {
}
@end 

ViewController2.h                                                                                                                    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *textFieldValue;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab;

- (IBAction)naz:(id)sender;



@end  

ViewController2.m                                                                                                                     #import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end


@implementation ViewController2


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"textFieldValue = %@", _textFieldValue);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)naz:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим у Вас есть два класса, класс `A` и класс `B`. Класс `А` - ввод данных и класс `В` - обработка данных. В методе, в котором мы обрабатываете вводимые данные, Вам необходимо создать экземпляр класса `В`.

```
- (void) someButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    MyClassB *classB = [[MyClassB alloc] init]; //создаете экземпляр класса
    classB.textFieldValue = _textField.text; // присваеваете значение переменной
}
```

В Вашем классе `B` в `.h` файле добавляете `property`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *textFieldValue;
```

Теперь переменная `textFieldValue` содержит значение, которое Вы передали ей в классе `А`.

Например в методе `viewDidLoad` (класс В) можете проверить:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   NSLog(@"textFieldValue = %@", _textFieldValue);
}
```

NB! Экземпляр класса, надо создавать только один раз, если при переходе на новый `view` Вы сделаете еще один экземпляр, то значение `_textFieldValue` будет `nil`.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Так как Вы создаете ссылку на новый контроллер в `IB`, Вам необходимо настроить `segue`. Для этого в `IB`, выделите связь между первым и вторым контроллером, во вкладке `Utilities` выберите `Attributes` и укажите `Identifier` - например `segueNext`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее для того, чтобы передать данные, Вам нужен метод

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

В котором Вы указываете нужное соединение, и передаете в контроллер данные. Вот пример:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueNext"])
    {
        ViewController2 *classB = [segue destinationViewController];
        classB.textFieldValue = _log.text;
    }
}
```

**Второй вариант**

Удалите из `IB` связи и сделайте переходы в коде. Например так:

```
- (IBAction)vper:(id)sender {
    ViewController2 *classB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    classB.textFieldValue = _log.text;
    [self presentViewController:classB animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только он ругается на _textField.text в (void) someButtonTapped (use of undeclared identifier '_textfield'), как быть?

Comment: `_textField` - замените это на название Вашего поля для ввода текста. Я написал `_textField` для примера.  Или для начала подставьте просто текст, например `classB.textFieldValue = @"Любой текст"`;

Comment: Сделал как Вы написали. Не получается.

Comment: Как скинуть код?

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос или же ссылку на ресурс

Comment: Что я не так делаю?

Comment: @Rad Вы не вызываете метод `someButtonTapped`! Перенесите код из данного метода в метод  `vper`

Comment: У меня null выдает при нажатии на vper, а результат пустая строка.

Comment: А вы в IB прикрепили элементы? Можете прислать ссылку на проект?

Comment: Конечно! Как это сделать?

Comment: Сделайте архив, положите его в DropBox например и ссылку сюда в комментарий

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/J6b4RD3lrvfe2 Ссылка!

Comment: @Rad отредактировал ответ.

Comment: method definition for 'prepareForSegue:' not found.

Comment: @Rad https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz3AhMsbCbl3N3JyMXFwWjJndEk

Comment: Не могу открыть ссылку

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/k82UuL0qryszt

Comment: Не правильно отправил.

Comment: Естественно на экране Вы не увидите изменений, так как результат выводиться только в логи. Чтобы увидеть на экране в классе ViewController2 в методе viewDidLoad добавьте данный код: _lab.text = self.textFieldValue;

Comment: Огромное спасибо от новичка! Теперь есть понимание! А как сделать, что б сохранялось значение, которое я ввожу?

Comment: Куда Вы его хотите сохранять? Так чтобы после повторного запуска программы, данные были введены? Тогда советую использовать CoreData.

Comment: Спасибо! Еще вопрос. Как тоже самое сделать, только значение, что бы менять не на UILabel а на кнопке UIButton?

Comment: [self.button setTitle:self.textFieldValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: У меня получилось, только как сделать что б до нажатии на button было видно значение?

Answer (score -1):

В одном контроллере можно сохранять данные в UserDefaults (или аналогичном менеджере данных) и считывать их в другом контроллере в методе viewWillAppear. Так данные сохранятся даже между перезапусками приложения.

Comment: вот за такое точно надо руки отрывать.

Comment: согласен, надо же до такого додуматься